# Using wildcard to find (and delete) matching files on a Linux box

Tags: linux, command-line, find, wildcards

I want to delete a specific config file for Awstats for every user on the box. What is the best way to delete them, and possibly, in one line?

All the files are under `/home` and have this structure:

```
/home/{username1}/domains/{domain1}/public_html/awstats/.data/awstats.{domain1}.conf
/home/{username1}/domains/{domain2}/public_html/awstats/.data/awstats.{domain2}.conf

/home/{username2}/domains/{domain1}/public_html/awstats/.data/awstats.{domain1}.conf
```

Some `/home/{username}/domains/` folders have multiple domain subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
rm /home/*/domains/*/public_html/awstats/.data/awstats.*.conf
```

?

Warning: if there is a file whose name is something like

```
/home/phred/domains/sci-fi/public_html/awstats/.data/awstats.fantasy.conf
```

i.e., the two occurrences of `{domain1}` don’t match, then the above command will delete it, too.  Is that a problem?

P.S. Unless verifying that the two occurrences of `{domain1}` match is what you’re asking about, or there’s something else that I’m missing, this question is not about regular expressions (regexs).  When `*`, `?`, and `[` (with a matching `]`) are used on the shell command line, they are called *wildcards*.

Comment: Clearly I was thinking way too difficult with regular expressions and xargs! I haven't tried just using *'s in the command, but it seemed to work just fine. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Glad to help.  May I draw your attention to [the **How do I ask questions?** section](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) of the Super User FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions) –– “When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the **accepted answer** by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.”  If you do that, we both benefit.  After you have earned some [reputation](http://superuser.com/faq#reputation), you can also [vote up](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) helpful answers by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `/home` run the following command

```
find . -name 'awstats*conf' | xargs rm
```

Before piping the result to `xargs` run the `find . -name 'awstas*.conf` by itself to verify that it lists only the files you want to remove.  Pipe to `xargs rm` only after you confirm th is.

The `find` when used as shown above will recursively look for files that match the regex specified.  For more information check the man pages for find and xargs.